# Operational planning for web app (backend)

Tags: performance, planning, devops

I know the question is a bit broad, but will give it a try.

I newly joined a backend team in our company that is about to release an app to external users, I noticed we don't have an operational plan, just basic monitoring and alerting, but I don't know how to come up with that plan.

I have some ideas but I am sure there's more systematic approach than this, anyway, this is what I came up with:

The operational plan will consists of 3 main parts:

**1. Monitoring & Alerting:**

- Networking:

  - latency
  - number of connections
  - request time
  - HTTP 200s rate
  - HTTP non-200s rate
- System:

  - CPU/Disk/Memory usage
  - Number of threads/workers
- Db:

  - Number of connections (RO & RW)
  - Failed/success queries rate
- Application:

  - Error & warnings rate
  - New Errors rate
- External Dependencies

**2. Performance Testing:**

- Scalability/Load/Stress testing
- Running canaries

**3. Contingency Plan:**

No idea yet, but I believe it's based on the outcome of the performance testing + rollback guide

So, If there's any guide I can follow or ideas on how operational plans should be constructed also pointing out stuff I am missing would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your company planning on using an IaaS like AWS or Azure? That will cover nearly all of the concerns you have for monitoring and alerting. Something I don't see mentioned is a deployment process. Blue/green deploys can cover you when you need to do a rollback and let you safely test in a true production environment before going live.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "operational plan"

Answer (score 0):

For me, the key thing to concentrate on for both fault during rollout and fault during live operation. Is to have a standard procedure you can implement that doesn't depend on diagnosing the fault.

For a deployment fault this would be your roll back plan. Ideally you are doing a blue/green deployment and can just put the old boxes back in load.

For a live fault rolling back to the previous version should still be an option. But you should also have "scale up" and "switch out" plans to enable you to replace a box like for like, or to add more capacity and finally a Disaster Recovery plan, where you switch to a whole new site in a different location.

You should also determine the triggers for when these plans are enacted. Don't leave it up to someone's call on the day. Agree in advance that if the error rate exceeds X then implement plan Y etc.

If you start with the plan and work back to the alerts required, you will get  list of things to monitor and the reason to monitor them.

Finally you need to practice your plans and make sure you have confidence that they can be implemented at any time. This means that you need to be able to run them with zero downtime.

Justifying all this effort for "things that will never happen" can be tough. It really needs to come from the top down, as if we are honest "we just go down while we try and fix it" is a viable strategy for many businesses.

Most business will at least have a "risk map" you can start adding things to though.